# How to implement ASP in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: asp.net, sublimetext

I'm working in Sublime Text 3. I want to implement ASP code with it. Is it possible to add ASP code with it or are there any plugins available to connect?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. The community here usually expects you to have done your own research before coming here. Therefore, please edit your question to identify the documentation/articles you have looked at, explaining why they didn't help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You have available Sublime Kulture, a Sublime Text 3 extension for ASP:
https://github.com/OmniSharp/Kulture

Hope it helps.